# Kilometric Calculation Function

Tags: laravel

I want to create a function to calculate the kilometric Fee which depends on the distance and the power of a car.

I use Laravel. I would like to create a controller function to calculate this. Does someone know how to achieve this?

I created two tables :

Bareme : 
id 
nm_distance 
mt_price

meeting : 
id_bareme 
nm_distance 
mt_indemnite_km 
mt_price

Comment: it's a business case how you'll calculate this. not a development issue at all

Comment: php artisan make:controller KilometricFeeController --- and you're away. The rest is just you building your business logic